# Meteor.bindEnvironment with node stream function loses context

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, node-pdfkit, node-streams

On calling a Meteor method with Meteor.bindEnvironment to create a new Fiber, the data context is no longer available. The insert ID returns undefined.

```js
Meteor.call('saveData', data, function(error, result){
    let returnValue = Collection.findOne({'data': result }).buffer;
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  'saveData': function(data) {
    let doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.image(data, 0, 0);
    doc.pipe(concat(Meteor.bindEnvironment(
      function(buffer) {
        let newID = Collection.insert({
          'data': buffer,
        });
      }
    )));
  }
  doc.end();
  return newID;
});
```

I have attempted using Meteor.bindAsync because I thought I would have a new Fiber and the original data context, but I still get the error that Meteor must run within a Fiber. How can I bind newID to the original data context to pass it back once the insert has finished?

Comment: Is `doc.pipe` sync or async?

Comment: It's an asynchronous node stream. I am using pdfkit.